# What is the purpose of angular-sanitize ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was just going through the examples for a angular and openlayers directive **[HERE](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive)** and came across the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/openlayers3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/angular-openlayers-directive.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/openlayers3/build/ol.css" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['openlayers-directive']);
        app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lon: 0,
                    autodiscover: true
                }
            });
       }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="DemoController">
    <openlayers ol-center="center"  height="400px"></openlayers>
    <h1>Center autodiscover example</h1>
    <form>
        Latitude : <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="center.lat" />
        Longitude : <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="center.lon" />
        Zoom : <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="center.zoom" />
        <button ng-click="center.autodiscover=true">Discover position</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The example can be seen as a live example **[HERE](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/022-center-autodiscover-example.html)**.

My question is about the files being loaded,  I don't quite understand why the below script being loaded:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

What is the purpose of the above script ?

**EDIT::** : i found out the git repo and the docs here for this module in angular **[HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)**. , but i still don't understand the purpose of this script , the documentation does't even have a single example.

I have coded in jQuery a fair bit , so can somebody explain this in jQuery terms ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you include the `angular-sanitize` script, inputs are sanitized by parsing the HTML into tokens. All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped html string. This means that no unsafe input can make it into the returned string.

I have included a small example below inspired by this [blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx). If you run this script with `var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);` the html links are rendered correctly. However, if you comment this statement out and uncomment `var app = angular.module("app", []);` the following error message is raised: `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- BEGIN disable refresh -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Including ngSanitize ensures html links get properly sanitized
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);
    //If you use this code instead no html links get displayed 
    //var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
      var main = this;

      main.links = [
        "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>",
        "<a href='http://odetocode.com'>OdeToCode</a>",
        "<a href='http://twitter.com'>Twitter</a>"
      ];
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <section ng-controller="mainController as main">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="link in main.links" ng-bind-html="link">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does it mean that `ng-sanitize` is only useful in cases where html input is dynamic or comes from client input? So when using only static html and template urls (from our own trusted domain (https) or from template cache) for loading html in our views/directives there is no need for `ng-sanitize`? Or are there other cases where `ng-sanitize` should be used.

Comment: `ng-sanitize` is not needed for static html, but should be used when the html input is dynamic or comes from client input, either directly or indirectly.