# angular 6 - send string contains quotation marks to component input

Tags: angular

I have a component with string input:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'abcComponent'
   template: `
      <div>
      ....
      </div>`
})
export class AbcComponent {
   @Input() text:string;
}
```

I want to send a string contains **quotation marks** to component (for example: abc"d):

```
   selector: 'parentComponent'
   template: `
      <div>
         <abcComponent [text]="'abc"d'"></abcComponent>
      </div>`
})
```

I also tried this:

```
<abcComponent [text]="'abc\"d'"></abcComponent>
```

But in both cases i get a template parse error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to do this is to sanitize your attribute value. Instead of using `<abcComponent [text]="'abc"d'"></abcComponent>`, use `<abcComponent [text]="'abc&quot;d'"></abcComponent>`, as `&quot;` is the "sanitized value" for the quotation marks.

Consider reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33209988/4216407) on how to sanitize HTML into tokens to properly escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

In component.ts

```
public text: string = 'abc\"d';
```

In component.html

```
<my-component [text]="text"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <abcComponent [text]="'abc &quot; d'"></abcComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will solve the problem

```
<abcComponent [text]='["abc\"d"]'></abcComponent>
```