# When to use ngsanitize?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I need to protect my data against an *xss* vulnerability.

Do I need use `ngsanitize` only when I also use `ng-bind-html` or also in other cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to sanitize data you know are safe. To explicitly trust a value you can use **$sce.trustAsHtml(value)**

> If a $sanitize service is unavailable and the bound value isn't explicitly trusted, you will have an exception (instead of an exploit.)

Source here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

**EDIT:**

NgSanitize escapes your data so you can safely render it on your html pages. It prevents any maliciously injected code from being executed on your page. This concerns dynamic data and user input (forms, url parameters, ...). Static content doesn't need sanitization. You can find an example of useful usage here: [What is the purpose of angular-sanitize ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209938/what-is-the-purpose-of-angular-sanitize)

Without ng-bind-html you don't need ng-sanitize. As long as you don't have any other dynamic data or user input rendered on your page.

Comment: If I am not using ngbindhtml then do I need to use ngsanitize.
And the main thing which I want to know is that on which condition should I use this sanitization of html. Can you tell me of any source to get a better clearity on the sanitization of html.